# Excel 2003 SUM from tabular data using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2003, excel-formula

I've been struggling with this one for a while... I have the following data table on a sheet called PickupData

[image]

I then have a sheet where i'm trying to sum income (col d) where org_code (col a) = the value in row 18 and month (col c) = the value in column a

[image]

I've tried with SUMPRODUCT, SUM(IF(blah,IF(blah,x,0),0) (pressing ctrl-shift-enter) and even the conditional sum wizard. I don't think i can use DSUM as it requires a cell range to be passed for the criteria parameter.

I also tried un-merging the cells as i thought this could be effecting the results.

Can anyone provide a working solution?

Heres the test workbook: [here](http://tickett.net/downloads/8917672.xls)

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sumproduct will work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D1:D8,--(A1:A8=OrgRef),--(C1:C8=MonthRef))
```

OrgRef and MonthRef are placeholders for the address of your filters.

In your example book the Org code is text while your "Org_Code" field where you have 26 entered is a number.  They won't match.  Either convert your org codes to numbers or preface 26 with a ' to mark it as a string.

Comment: genius- thank you! how could you tell some of the numbers were stored as strings? i'd expect excel to highlight the cells like it normally does with numbers stored as strings. also- what is the purposed of the --?

Comment: The most obvious sign is Excel left justifies strings and right justifies values.  This can be overridden but is a good first check.  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: damn- didnt realise but i actually tested this in excel 2010 on the mac (neither of the other solutions i tried worked before in 2010 or 2003)- this one now tried on 2003 doesn't seem to work. if you manage to get it working could you upload my modified .xls pleae?

Comment: Small bit of progress- the range seems to not allow D:D style... has to be explicitly defined D1:D8 (just experimenting to see if header row can/musn't be included

Comment: there seem to be a few weird limitations... not allowed named ranges or "entire column" D:D style references... but D1:D10000 works aok

Comment: You could use named ranges but it would need to be individual columns.  I would avoid using D:D type references, it can introduce long calculation delays.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SUMIF()
SUMIFS()
```

or, Excel Macros?

## Code

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim rRange As Range
    Set rRange = Range("C:C")

    Dim iSum As Integer
    For Each rRange In rRange

        If (rRange.Offset(0, -2) = 18) Then
            iSum = iSum + rRange.Value
        End If

        If (IsEmpty(rRange.Offset(1, 0))) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rRange

    Debug.Print iSum
End Sub
```

Comment: SUMIFS came in, in Excel 2007 and SUMIF doesn't support multiple criteria.

Comment: i am starting to think i may need to write a user defined function. could you explain the one you pasted? for each non-empty cell in column return the sum of all column c values where column a = 18?

Answer (score 0):

The SUM(IF(... should work, but yes you will need to un-merge your cells because array-formulas do not work in merged cells.  The following entered into B19 should work (remembering to ctrl+shift+enter)

```
=SUM(IF(PickupData!$A$2:$A$8=B$18,IF(PickupData!$C$2:$C$8=$A19,PickupData!$D$2:$D$8,0),0))
```

Comment: tried that but no joy- i've uploaded the workbook and linked in the question if you have time to check for a mistake- thanks